# Как скрыть кнопку после нажатия, а после 5 секунд чтобы она появилась снова jquery?

Tags: jquery

Я сделал так чтобы после одного нажатия кнопка исчезала, но нужно чтобы секунд через 5 кнопка появлялась обратно.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $(this).hide(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).show();
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#two').click(function() {
    $(this).hide(function() {
      setTimeout(function(btn) {
        $(btn).fadeIn();
      }, 2000, this);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="two">Click Me</button>
```

```
setTimeout(btn => $(btn).fadeIn(), 2000, this);

setTimeout(() => $(this).fadeIn(), 2000);

setTimeout((function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }).bind(this), 2000);

var btn = this;
setTimeout(function() { $(btn).fadeIn(); }, 2000);
```